# Create a dll that changes a few functions of another dll

Tags: c++, dll, hook, code-injection, dll-injection

I want to create a dll, that will reference any function that is not defined in the dll to another dll.

How do i get the dll to change the behavior of a few functions of another dll, but keep the other functions the same.

What is the syntax to my dll  "for every function that is not a, b, c import the function from shell32.dll. for function a b c do ......"

I want to do so without reverse engineering the dll. and without copying the entire set of function in shell32.dll

Comment: You need to lay out your exact requirements explicitly. It seems as if you're trying to create a proxy DLL that handles every possible system call in windows, but forwards the ones that it does not want to handle to the appropriate call in a windows system dll? Why? This is a serious question. Anything you think you want to achieve by doing this can be done more easily another way.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs can contain forwarders, but this is a limitative list. Anything not listed is not forwarded. Wouldn't matter much, anyway: your import lib declares the same list of functions, so `RandomWindows9Function(HWND)` will not be in your import lib. The linker therefore will not put in a dependency to your DLL for it. The function will simply be found in the Windows 9 SDK, and the linker will add a dependency to Kernel32.dll.